# How does Minimax/Alpha-Beta pruning prioritize shorter paths?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm working on a simple tic-tac-toe problem, I'm and trying to understand how the Minimax algorithm works.

If I use the utility function 1 for X win, -1 for O win, and 0 for game in progress, then I don't understand how the algorithm prioritizes shorter solutions.
As I understand it goes to the deepest node first, and event if it's not the shortest path, but it leads to a possible win, then it'll pick it.

Let me explain in the example. Here's the state of the board and X turn (the notation is from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tic-tac-toe):

```
OX_
_X_
__O
```

If we search from top left position to the right down, then the algorithm will find that if we put X in the position (0, 2) cause it leads to inevitable win next turn:

```
OXX
_X_
__O
```

However, a smarter choice would be (2, 1) and the immediate winning position:

```
OX_
_X_
_XO
```

I don't see how Minimax or Alpha-Beta pruning would prioritize such behavior.

So my question is if I understand it correctly, and how I could improve it.

Comment: Change your utility function to take into account the number of turns.

Comment: Instead of 1 for X win, use N for X win, where N is the number of blank spaces left on the board.  That way, choice (2,1) has value 4, whereas choice (0,2) has value 2 (since the win will occur with only 2 empty spaces left).

Answer (score 0):

Minimax for Tic Tac Toe has few possible numerical valuations: win, lose, draw. The Minimax algorithm assigns the maximum of all the ways the player's position could be minimized by the other player's subsequent moves. A win in the next move would be assigned Infinity, the clear choice. Otherwise, in Tic Tac Toe, it will prioritize a draw except for a few special cases, such as winning in the next move or being able to create a fork (leading to a certain win in the move after next).

Alpha Beta pruning is an optimization method that avoids exploring sections of the search tree when it can be shown that any part of the section would yield a worse result than one that has already been found; for example, say one full node exploration yielded a potential draw and another node's leaf showed a loss; there would be no sense in exploring other children of the latter node (unless you assumed the other player would not always play their best move). You might find this link helpful: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe_AI.html